# Extract-ing variables from previous array without keys?

Tags: php

I have an array that just looks like this:

```
print_r ($custDataColumns);
Array ( [0] => firstName [1] => lastName )
```

It's created from a previous mySQL call. I need to create variables from the values (in this case, $firstName and $lastName). Seems like extract would do this easily, using the below:

```
extract($custDataColumns);
```

PHP throws no errors, however I have no idea how you would reference the variables afterwards as it seems the variable would be named $[0] or $0 from other PHP examples I have seen. Is there a way to extract a PHP Array that does not have user defined keys?

Note: I don't need the variables to have data in them yet, I just need them created at this point to set data at a later point in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-parameters), you can find that:

> You must use an associative array; a numerically indexed array will not produce results unless you use `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` or `EXTR_PREFIX_INVALID`.

So the solution is:

```
$custDataColumns = ['firstName','lastName'];
print_r ($custDataColumns);
extract($custDataColumns, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'myvar');
// now extracted variables are prefixed with `myvar_` because
// "Prefixes are automatically separated from the array key by an underscore character."
var_dump($myvar_0, $myvar_1);   // what you need
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$firstname = "Peter";
$lastname = "Griffin";
$age = "41";

$result = compact("firstname", "lastname", "age");

print_r($result);
```

Comment: You declared variables and then you are using `compact`. I think the OP needs somthing else.

Comment: You should explain the code in the answers you write.